# Dynamically call functions/subs in method using variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I found an answer on here that doesn't quite work, so I thought I would ask specifically what I am looking for.

I have function names stored in the database that are tied to specific objects.

I query the database, return the function name for the object, and now I'm trying to use that data to call the function.

For example, I have an object 'BOTTLE' and a function called 'OPEN BOTTLE'. When I'm using 'BOTTLE' I want to call 'OPEN BOTTLE'.

I found this:

```
    CallByName(ME, "FunctionName", CallType.Method)
```

But it doesn't work because I have the functions stored in a separate method in my code. In won't let me pass in the method in instead of ME, and I can't inherit it because it is a method.

I cannot change it from a method to something else because it's used in more than one location throughout the system, and would potentially cause it to break.

Is there another option that I can use? I tried using reflection but ran into the same problem.

I'm using VB.net in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why don't you use one method and pass that name as parameter? Then use it for an `if-else` or `Select...Case`.

Comment: As it stands now there will be 30 of these, and it's only going to grow. I'm trying to make this as easy to update and maintain as possible. Each object has 4 functions it uses, and they aren't shared across multiple objects.

Comment: I can't tell what you have tried and what didn't work - maybe show some more code that illustrates what you are trying to do.  Did you read the [documentation for `CallByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?  The 2nd parameter is the function name - e.g. `CallByName(aBottle, "OpenBottle", CallType.Method)`.  You may be better off using the .NET Reflection APIs instead.

Comment: The functions I'm using, as stated in the question above, are in a method. CallByName doesn't allow the passing of methods in the first parameter, only objects. I tried using reflection, but it also requires an object and not a method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "functions I'm using... are in a method" could mean.  Are they lambda expressions stored in variables?  Showing some code would really help in understanding your question.

Comment: I have a method that is a large amount of stored procedures. Based on what the user selects in a combobox, I'm returning a list of available stored procedures that are used to return various pieces of data. For example: If someone selects "User Count" then I want to use the stored procedure will return the data for that selection. I'm trying to make the application so all I have to do is add some information in the database, update the stored procs file, and the selection will become active and usable.